# React - how to determine clientHeight of dynamic element in a dynamic component?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a requirement in a project that we have an accordion component with action buttons in the summary container.  This is raising issues with 508 accessibility, since we can't nest interactive components.  We have devised some code that puts a placeholder for the buttons in the actual accordion code, then have a separate div, outside of the accordion block but within the repeating li, that builds the buttons.  So far, so good, and it is accessibility friendly.

The last hurdle is getting the elements to line up vertically centered in a responsive environment.  What we are trying to do is, in the separate button div, make a JS call to a small script that gets the clientHeight from one of the summary elements, proposalName, and use that, along with the math function, to dynamically add a top style to the buttons to control the vertical position.  The problem with this, as near as we can tell, is that the propName height is not found until react has rendered the page, by which time the js script returns undefined to top.

Pertinent code blocks:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as constants from "../common/constants";
import { Theme, createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


export class ProposalSubmissionHistory extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            expanded: false
        };

    ...

    strDivHeight = (number) => { setTimeout(function () {
            const name = "propname_" + number;
            const elem = document.getElementById(name);
            const height = elem.clientHeight / 2 + 15;
            const top = height;
            return top;
        }, 1);
    };


    render() {
        const proposal = this.props.proposal;
        var content = (
            <div className="secondary-accordion">
                <Accordion expanded={this.state.expanded} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <AccordionSummary
                        aria-controls={`panel-${proposal.proposalId}-content`}
                        id={`panel-${proposal.proposalId}-header`}
                    >
                        <div className="accordion-inner-header">
                            <div className="inner-title" id={"propname_" + proposal.proposalId}>{this.props.proposal.proposalName}</div>
                            <div className="inner-secondary">
                                <div className="submit-date past-date">
                                    <div className="submit-text">Submitted on <span className="submit-time">{this.props.proposal.proposalCreateDateString}<small>{this.props.proposal.proposalCreateTimeString}</small></span></div>
                                </div>
                                {this.props.isActive &&
                                    <div className="vertical-center">
                                        <div className="button-placeholder" style={{ width: 120, height: 30 }}>&nbsp;</div>
                                    </div>
                                }
                                <div className="inner-accordion-arrow accordion-trigger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target={`question-secondary-${proposal.proposalId}-accordion`}><img src="./images/icon-arrow-right-mdgray.svg" alt="arrow-down"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </AccordionSummary>
                    <AccordionDetails>
                        ...
                    </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
                {this.props.isActive &&
                    <div className="control-posit visible" style={{ top: this.strDivHeight(proposal.proposalId) }}>
                        <div className="button-container">
                            {this.props.isActive &&
                                <Link to={`/reviseProposal/${proposal.proposalId}`}>
                                    <button className="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root med-btn-primary" aria-label={`button-to-${proposal.proposalId}`} tabIndex="0" onClick={this.handleRevise} type="button">
                                        <span className="MuiButton-label">
                                            Revise
                                        </span>
                                        <span className="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </Link>}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        );

        return (content);
    }
}

    export default ProposalSubmissionHistory;
```

Empirically, we understand we need to pause the render so that that the script can get the clientHeight values, but have not been able to determine where and when to do that.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!!